# How to list users in group email in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a Microsoft Graph API to list users in group email like the feature Outlook has?

If this API exists, when use it on

```
group1engineers@example.com
```

it will list

```
 - jack@example.com
 - tom@example.com
 - rose@example.com
 - etc.
```

**UPDATE 1**: tried

```
GET /groups/group1engineers@example.com/members
```

on [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) (have access Directory.ReadWrite.All)

But error 400

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid object identifier 'group1engineers@example.com'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "dad057af-2b67-4186-bc8c-df2b10fc2d0c",
            "date": "2018-02-02T09:53:51"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: tried

```
GET /groups?$filter=mail eq 'group1engineers@example.com'
GET /groups?$filter=mailNickname eq 'group1engineers'
```

Both get same results, still no group members show up (this group has 7 members):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "4822c6e4-91b5-4db8-ae1a-2a52353f8c28",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2017-09-01T08:13:42Z",
            "description": null,
            "displayName": "Group 1 Engineers",
            "groupTypes": [],
            "mail": "group1engineers@example.com",
            "mailEnabled": true,
            "mailNickname": "group1engineers",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": "2017-11-16T20:47:17Z",
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": "S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-28525981",
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": true,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [
                "x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=63886b35b89a410dacad845a76016073-GROUP1ENGINEERS",
                "X500:/o=microsoft/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=3f0ecc97b6be4ff08bac734225ae5a30-GROUP1ENGINEERS",
                "X500:/o=microsoft/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=beac216013b54a78a81cad98bdb34df0-GROUP1ENGINEERS",
                "smtp:group1engineers@example.onmicrosoft.com",
                "smtp:group1engineers@service.example.com",
                "smtp:group1engineers@064d.mgd.example.com",
                "SMTP:group1engineers@example.com"
            ],
            "renewedDateTime": "2017-09-01T08:13:42Z",
            "securityEnabled": false,
            "visibility": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the group members using the Graph API. From https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members
```

Note that it isn't transitive, so if a group contains another group, you have to run through all the children.

To search for the group and get its members at once, you can use the $filter and $expand query parameters:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailNickname eq 'group1engineers'&$expand=members
```

The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group#properties) contains information about which properties that can be $filter'ed. Look for the text "Supports $filter" in the property descriptions.

Comment: I believe it wants the ID from Azure AD for that group (it's a GUID). You can look up the ID by using the List Groups operation (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list) with a $filter expression on the mailNickName property.

Comment: Thanks, but still failed to get group members. Added in UPDATE 2 in question.

Comment: Did you try using the group's ID 4822c6e4-91b5-4db8-ae1a-2a52353f8c28 as the ID in the  members call ```GET /groups/4822c6e4-91b5-4db8-ae1a-2a52353f8c28/members```?

Comment: Oh, it works now! Ok, it means I need two steps to get group members. If there is an one step api, that will be awesome.

Comment: That&amp;#39;s where the expand query parameter can help you. Try running this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailNickname eq &amp;#39;group1engineers&amp;#39;&amp;$expand=members`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'm using the SO app on my phone

Comment: Thanks @RasmusW! Please format that or add in the answer, so I can accept. Right now `&amp;#39;` will cause issue.